# How to check for palindromes in python?

Tags: python, boolean

Can you write a method that checks whether a word or a phrase is a palindrome?

NOTE: Palindrome is a word which reads the same backwards. Eg = madam, racecar or phrases like "nurses run".

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: "Can you" - yes, I could. But I don't think this is the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Ty Nico, that was helpful. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def palindrome(s):
    
    s = s.replace(' ','') # This replaces all spaces ' ' with no space ''. (Fixes issues with strings that have spaces)
    return s == s[::-1]   # Check through slicing
palindrome('nurses run')
```